# How to Inset + tweak Depth using numeric input

Tags: edit-mode

[image]

I used Inset Faces <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to tweak but I cannot use the numlock key to make it 0.1. When I do that the thickness changes, not the tweak. Is there a different way to do it, or can I use a certain shortcut that I don't know about? I cannot find any other way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change multiple parameters for an Operator numericaly, use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key:

1. Press <kbd>I</kbd> to inset
2. (Optional) Enter numeric value for the Thickness
3. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch over to Depth
4. Enter numeric value for the Depth
5. Confirm operator with <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this is to simply inset with any values and then use the redo panel to the left to manipulate settings like depth:

[image: redo voodoo]

The tweak value is a myth...

Comment: Yeah you right, just occurred to me there is no tweak and it is named Depth. I got carried by the original wording of the question:)